# Array of JPanels on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
public frame() {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
   frame.setSize(400,300);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
   int i = 4;
   int j = 4;
   JPanel[][] panelHolder = new JPanel[i][j];

   for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
       for (int b = 0; b < j; b++) {
           panelHolder[a][b] = new JPanel();
           add(panelHolder[a][b]);
       }
   }
   panelHolder[3][2].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
   JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
   panelHolder[0][0].add(enter);

   frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I try to add a component to a panel or set the color nothing changes, I used this code from elsewhere but I wrote it down the other day and can't find it again, but the loops are adding the JPanels to the frame right? so why can't I add to the JPanels?

Comment: why do you have the constructor and a JFrame with the same name?

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve] when asking why your code is not working. You'll get much better answers if we can actually compile and run your code. Please read the link -- the mcve should be short, should compile and run for us, should not be in a link. Luck.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have an object in your constructor with the same name as your class, but when calling `setVisible()`, you are not using it. You can solve that by making your class extend `JFrame`, and then using this constructor:

```
public frame() {
    setSize(400, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    int i = 4;
    int j = 4;
    JPanel[][] panelHolder = new JPanel[i][j];

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < j; b++) {
            panelHolder[a][b] = new JPanel();
            add(panelHolder[a][b]);
        }
    }
    panelHolder[3][2].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
    panelHolder[0][0].add(enter);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: The variable name has nothing to do with the problem. It's confusing, yes, but not the cause of the problem (that we can tell yet).

Comment: I'm not saying that your code doesn't work, but it doesn't explain why **his code** doesn't work.

Comment: His problem is that he's using two JFrames, but the name of the variable is not the issue. He could name it Foobar and the problem would remain.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I noticed the problem in my answer and corrected the explanation. Thanks! (I might add that it's very flattering to be noticed by SO 'celebrities' XD)

Comment: I'm no celebrity. 1+ for a decent answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not a celebrity but you're well known here for your well explained answers on Swing related questions, along with some others. And Itamar nice catch about the two frames, 1+ for that